# Javascript array reverse function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a question with my homework

```
var NumberOfString = new Array(5);
NumberOfString = prompt("정수 5개를 입력하세요: ");
document.write("입력된 수의 배열" + "<br/>" + NumberOfString + "<hr>");
document.write("역순으로 재정렬된 배열" + "<br>");
document.write(NumberOfString.reverse());
```

This is my code. The function `array.reverse` doesn't work. I want to know why? Thanks!

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_". Notice also, that String doesn't have `reverse` method.

Comment: You are overriding your initial array `NumberOfString` with the result of the `prompt` function which will be a string or null

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse `string` with `NumberOfString.split('').reverse().join('')`.

**Note**

When you write `NumberOfString = prompt("정수 5개를 입력하세요: ");` it will convert your `NumberOfString` `array` to `string` as `prompt` returns the `string`.

`String` do not have `reverse` method. But you can use `split('')` to convert it to `array` then perform `reverse` and `join` it to get reverse string.

```js
var NumberOfString = new Array(5);
NumberOfString = prompt("정수 5개를 입력하세요: ");
document.write("입력된 수의 배열" + "<br/>" + NumberOfString + "<hr>");
document.write("역순으로 재정렬된 배열" + "<br>");
document.write(NumberOfString.split('').reverse().join(''));
```

Comment: It's woked! Thanks! Can you tell me this is why? why should i use the split method?

Comment: i got it! But how to get user input without using prompt method?

Comment: As I mentioned in answer also that `split('')` will convert `string` into `char` `array`. And you can perform `reverse` on `array`.

Comment: Add `input` box in you form. And get value from there.

Comment: my teacher let us use the ```prompt```method . This confuses me...

Answer (score 0):

because the type of NumberOfString is string. 
You can try this:

```
var NumberOfString = new Array(5);
var anySymbol = ''; 
NumberOfString = prompt("정수 5개를 입력하세요: ");
document.write("입력된 수의 배열" + "<br/>" + NumberOfString + "<hr>");
document.write("역순으로 재정렬된 배열" + "<br>");
document.write(NumberOfString.split(anySymbol).reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the last line.

> reverse() method works with arrays

so you have to convert your string to an array by split() method.

and then set it back to a string by using join() method

```js
var NumberOfString = new Array(5);
NumberOfString = prompt("정수 5개를 입력하세요: ");
document.write("입력된 수의 배열" + "<br/>" + NumberOfString + "<hr>");
document.write("역순으로 재정렬된 배열" + "<br>");
// here you have to convert the string to an array by split('')
// then use reverse method therfore set it back to a string by join('')
document.write(NumberOfString.split('').reverse().join(''));
```